# Msaccess update query issue

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a weird scenario with update query. The update query used in access code is working in my system where as it doesn’t work in other system. It is abruptly closing the session.
Any suggestions on work around or root cause?

Note: both the system use same version of msaccess

Comment: A few questions: Are you using an identical data model in your version to that of the test where it is not working? Also, does the Update query use anything other than SQL? For example, does it use a VBA function, DMax, etc.? Also, how is the Update query being fired (i.e.; DoCmd.OpenQuery, ADO, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Repairing and Compacting the DB that is failing, on the machine or device it is failing on? If the DB is not compiled (i.e. it is not saved as an accde or mde), you can try Repairing and Compacting, as described in this Microsoft article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2

Sometimes when you distribute an Access databases, the compilation state fails because of missing or version issues with project references (the version of ADODB, for example). Repairing and Compacting can help with this.

Comment: Looks like msaccess issue! After reinstalling ms access it worked